# Use dynamic property from test in service implementation

Tags: spring-boot

I am using keycloak-testcontainer to implement authorization tests.

I am doing as follows in my testclass

`
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:" + port;
}

```
@DynamicPropertySource
static void registerResourceServerIssuerProperty(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id", () -> "my-client-id");   
    registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret", () -> "my-client-secret");        
    registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri", () -> keycloak.getAuthServerUrl() + "auth/realms/myrealm");
    registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri", () -> keycloak.getAuthServerUrl() + "auth/realms/myrealm");
    registry.add("spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri", () -> keycloak.getAuthServerUrl() + "auth/realms/myrealm");
}
```

`

Now during the test execution a service method is called that does another request against the keycloak

The class reads values as follows

```
@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret}")
private String clientSecret;

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
private String tokenBaseUrl;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

My expectation was, that the values are coming from the DynamicPropertySource instead the properties file.

But I recognize that the Service implementation takes them from the application.properties file located under src/test/resources

How can I acheive, that the service takes the values defined during startup of the test instead of application.properties